# transform json to key/value file in bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a JSON which looks like this:

```
{
    "lorem": "ipsum",
    "dolor": "sid",
    "data": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    }
}
```

and I want an output which is ini like where I only need the content of 'data' (which is always flat, no branches). The output should look like this:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

I can use jq (just don't get it running) but have to use a bash script for it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Post your research efforts into the question

Comment: What does "I can use jq (just don't get it running)" mean???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -r '.data | to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\(.value)"' input.json
```

The output:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

Comment: @MatiasBarrios, there are 2 moments: 1) the OP have written **I can use jq** ; 2) **jq** tag is ON

Comment: I actually can, but great to have a solution without it, too. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in BASH.

```
#!/bin/bash

all_keys=$( cat input.txt );

while read key
do
    grep "$key" ./text.txt | awk -F':' '{ print $1"="$2}' | tr -d '[", ]'
done <<< "$all_keys"
```

Assuming you values are in *text.txt* and that you have your keys in *input.txt*.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

In python
This reads stdin and outputs the desired "key=value" one per line

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
import sys

data = sys.stdin.read()

json_structure=json.loads(data)

start_point=json_structure["data"]

for k in start_point.keys():
    print("%s=%s" % (k, start_point[k]))
```

If I was using python to unmangle the json input however, I would probably rewrite the bash script in python